# How to explore nested zip without extract?

Tags: unix, unzip

In bash, I use `unzip -l` in order to show the content of a zip without extract its content.

My question: what command should I use if I have nested zip files and I want to explore also the content of nested zip inside?

Example:

```
file1.zip
   |
   |
   ----- textfile.txt
   ----- file2.zip
```

How to do unzip -l to file2.zip without extract both file1.zip and file2.zip?

Comment: Tried zipinfo -1 file1.zip, but it prints the same as unzip -l file1.zip

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the standard behavior of any of the common bash zip utilities.. You have to extract the zip beforehand, but you could make a script that extracted just the zips inside the root of file1.zip, called `unzip -l` and then cleaned up after itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

unzip -l file1.zip

for f in $(unzip -Z1 file1.zip); do
       if [ ${f: -4} == ".zip" ]
       then
           unzip -q -d . file1.zip $f
           unzip -l $f
           rm $f
       fi
done;
```

Output:

```
Archive:  file1.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      312  2018-05-04 00:52   file2.zip
        0  2018-05-04 00:52   textfile.txt
---------                     -------
      312                     2 files
Archive:  file2.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2018-05-04 00:22   file2
        0  2018-05-04 00:52   textfile.txt
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this java based utility [nzip](https://github.com/ankitkaushal/nzip) for nested zips. Extracting and compressing nested zips can be done easily using following commands. The list command should be the one useful for you:

```
java -jar nzip.jar -c list -s readme.zip

java -jar nzip.jar -c extract -s "C:\project\readme.zip" -t readme

java -jar nzip.jar -c compress -s readme -t "C:\project\readme.zip"
```